# Help installing delayed_job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, delayed-job

I'm trying to use collectiveidea's delayed_job gem
The installation instructions include

```
Rake tasks are not automatically loaded from gems, so you’ll need to add
the following to your Rakefile:

begin
  require 'delayed/tasks'
rescue LoadError
  STDERR.puts "Run `rake gems:install` to install delayed_job"
end
```

Where is my Rakefile? And what is a Rakefile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Rakefile](http://rake.rubyforge.org/files/doc/rakefile_rdoc.html) is a file that is used to configure [rake](http://rake.rubyforge.org/), a Ruby build tool (sort of like [make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/), but all in Ruby).  In a Rails project, there is a file in the top project directory named Rakefile where you can insert this code.

Alternatively, you can add a file into the lib/tasks directory (for example named delayed_job.rake) and put the code into there.  The name of the file is not important as long as

1. It is in the lib/tasks directory
2. It has the extension .rake

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with rails 3.1 and collectiveidea-delayed_job.

Once I added `Delayed::Worker.backend = :active_record` in the initializer I got the error
`no such file to load -- delayed/backend/active_record (LoadError)`

The solution for me was to add `gem 'delayed_job_active_record'` in the gemfile, as suggested [here](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/issues/314)

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem and put that code in delayed_job.rake in the lib/tasks directory. It works, but now It say's:

```
*** Starting job worker localhost pid:79949 
rake aborted! 
uninitialized constant Delayed::Job
```

What is wrong now?

UPDATE: I just got a mail answer from Brandon:

Theres a bug in the latest version where it doesn't get properly initialized when using the rake task.  If you create a file in config/initializers and put the follow in it, the error should go away:

```
Delayed::Worker.backend = :active_record
```